# Cardinality constraints unsatisfiable

Tags: alloy

I am having trouble getting Alloy's cardinality operator (`#`) working as expected, even on simple examples.

For instance, the following Alloy file...

```
sig Y {}

sig X {r : Y -> Y} {
//#r = 2
}

run {} for exactly 1 X, 3 Y
```

... gives me a solution that happens to contain 2 `r`-edges (see picture below). However, if I uncomment the `#r = 2` line, Alloy can find no solutions! What am I doing wrong?

[image]

---

**Edit.** I have discovered that this problem only affects [AlloyStar](http://alloy.csail.mit.edu/alloy/hola/) (as opposed to vanilla Alloy). When using AlloyStar (version 0.2) I get

> **Executing "Run run$1 for exactly 1 X, 3 Y"**
>
> Solver=minisatprover(jni) Bitwidth=1 MaxSeq=0 Symmetry=20
>
> 69 vars. 12 primary vars. 167 clauses. 923ms.
>
> Instance found. Predicate is consistent. 21ms.

but when I uncomment the `#r = 2`, I get

> **Executing "Run run$1 for exactly 1 X, 3 Y"**
>
> Solver=minisatprover(jni) Bitwidth=1 MaxSeq=0 Symmetry=20
>
> 0 vars. 0 primary vars. 1 clauses. 15ms.
>
> No instance found. Predicate may be inconsistent. 1ms.

So I guess this question has thus become a bug report for the AlloyStar developers!

Comment: Strange. I can produce instances, even after uncommenting the line.

Comment: @dejvuth That's interesting! I'm actually using AlloyStar, so that may be the cause of my problem. I will probe further...

Comment: I can confirm, it works just fine on Alloy 4.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report.  There are several things going on here.  Essentially, everything [danielp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36217065/cardinality-constraints-unsatisfiable#answer-36258099) said is correct, but the full answer is a bit more nuanced.

First of all, I'm assuming you have the "Forbid Overflows" option set to true, because otherwise you would get an instance regardless of the specified scope (bitwidth) for integers.

Next, let's not use "appended facts", because appended facts can have different semantics depending on whether the "Enable Implicit This" option is enabled.  So let's assume the following Alloy model:

```
sig Y {}
sig X {r: Y -> Y} 

fact { #r = 2 }

run {} for exactly 1 X, 3 Y
```

Now, in Alloy4.2, when no integer bound is specified, the default bitwidth used by the engine to represent integer expressions (e.g., cardinality expressions, integer constants, etc.) is 5; since constant 2 is representable in 5 bits, no overflow happens and an instance is found.

In Alloy*, on the other hand, the default bitwidth is 1, which is not wide enough to represent constant 2, hence, overflow happens and no instance is found.  Why bitwidth 1 was chosen as the default?  I'm not 100% sure, but it was probably because support for bit vectors was added, as well as some synthesis benchmarks using bit vectors, so at the of writing it was convenient to do so.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have to configure the bitwidth:

> Executing "Run run$1 for exactly 1 X, 3 Y"
>
> Solver=minisatprover(jni) **Bitwidth=1** MaxSeq=0 Symmetry=20
>
> 0 vars. 0 primary vars. 1 clauses. 15ms.
>
> No instance found. Predicate may be inconsistent. 1ms.

The number 2 cannot be represented with a bitwidth of 1. I suppose that the example works in standard Alloy because the default bitwidth is higher there.